# Method invocation highlighed error in Android Studio

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-studio

Im a little bit confused in Android Studio. I didint seen this kind of errors in Eclipse before.

Example:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction tf = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AddDialogFragment.TAG);
```

this code is working fine, but fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); gets highlighted and says: 
Method invocation 'fragmentManager.beginTransaction' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' less... (Ctrl+F1)

This inspection reports those conditions in the specified inspection scope that are always true or false, as well as points out where a RuntimeException may be thrown, based on data flow analysis of the code. This inspection also reports Nullable/NotNull contract violations. Annotations to support the contract can be configured (by default @Nullable/@NotNull annotations from annotations.jar will be used)

Do i have to check for Null before?

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    if(fragmentManager != null)
       FragmentTransaction tf = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment oldFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AddDialogFragment.TAG);
```

I have never seen this in any Tut or Example before.
If this is a stupid question than sorry, but im still a beginner :)
.

Comment: in order to avoid NPE you always have to check if the returned reference is null

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I've seen, Android Studio shows a bit too much warnings about potential `NullPointerExceptions`, even for methods that will never return null. I simply ignore some of them, but it's useful to carefully check all of them, because sometimes I missed an important one.

If you look at the android source code, it's easy to see that `getFragmentManager()` will never return null :

```
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    return mFragments;
}
```

Where mFragments is assigned only once through the whole class :

```
final FragmentManagerImpl mFragments = new FragmentManagerImpl();
```

Comment: Is there any chance to reduce such verbosity? IDEA doesn't have such problem.

Comment: @mente This will most likely be fixed in the future. The last version already shows less warnings than before.

Comment: According to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742471/ , `getFragmentManager()` returns `null` if the fragment isn't attached to activity

Answer (score 0):

In `androidx` use `requireFragmentManager()` instead. Otherwise, use [getParentFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragmentManager()).

That will make the warnings go away. Google added these APIs for this very reason.